# Retrieve the Active Record Association name between two classes\models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to know how to retrieve the *Active Record Association* name between two classes\models.

That is, I have two models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
end
```

and I would like to retrieve (on runtime) them association name, in this case `accounts` and `users` strings.

**Is it possible? If so, how can I do that?**

---

**UPDATE**

If I have more association statements in `User` and `Account` classes (see the below example), how can I retrieve *exactly* the `User` `Account` association name?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  has_many :articles
  belongs_to :authorization
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

?

```
User.reflect_on_all_associations.each do |assoc|
  puts "#{assoc.macro} #{assoc.name}"
end
#=> "has_many accounts"
```

**UPD**

```
User.reflect_on_all_associations.select{|a| a.class_name == "Account"}.each do |assoc|
  puts "#{assoc.macro} #{assoc.name}"
end
#=> "has_many accounts"
```

Comment: And if I have more association statements in the User and Account classes? How can I retrieve exactly the 'User' 'Account' association?